# Concerning Hurwitz Zeta function, how to prove the following identity?

Tags: integration, special-functions, gamma-function, zeta-functions

It is claimed that

$$\zeta'(0,s)=\ln\left(\frac{\Gamma(s)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)$$

where the derivative is meant by the first argument (as usual with Hurwitz Zeta).

How to prove this?

Wolfram Alpha confirms this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D[HurwitzZeta[s%2C+p]%2C+s]+at+s%3D0 but I have no other clue.

Is there a more general form of the identity (with a variable instead of 0)?

Comment: i have the feeling that the connection to Polygamma functions could be really useful here especially the third formula of the last paragraph, described here: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygammafunktion

Comment: @tired I do not see how the formula is connected here.

Comment: you have a deriviative of $\zeta$ conected to other functions with well known properties. Furthermore the relation holds for all $s$, this should be enough to have a very sharp look at it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok let's see:

There is a famous integral representation for the Hurwitz function due to Hermite which reads as follows:

$$
\zeta(s,a)= \frac{a^{-s}}{2}+\frac{a^{1-s}}{1-s}+2\int_0^{\infty}dt \frac{\sin(s\arctan(t/a))}{(e^{2 \pi t}-1)(t^2+a^2)^{s/2}} \quad (1)
$$

You may check for yourself that it is allowed to switch differentiation w.r.t to $s$ with integration.

So the next task is differentiating and taking the limit afterwards, because this is straightforward but tedious i will omit the details here and just state that

$$
\zeta'(0,a)= \frac{-\log(a)}{2}+ a\log(a)-a +2\int_0^{\infty}dt \frac{\arctan(t/a)}{e^{2 \pi t}-1}
$$

Because we have our lucky day, the remaining integral is [well known](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsLogGammaFormulas.html):

$$
2\int_0^{\infty}dt \frac{\arctan(t/a)}{e^{2 \pi t}-1}= \log(\Gamma(a))- \log(a)(1/2-a)+a-\log(2\pi)/2 \quad (2)
$$

Putting everything together we obtain the desired result:

$$
\zeta'(0,a)=\log\left(\frac{\Gamma(a)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)
$$

Edit: One way to proof (1) is by the aid of [the famous Abel-Plana formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula) using the fact that $\frac{1}{(\pm i t+a)^s}=\frac{e^{ \pm i s\arctan(t/a)}}{( t^2+a^2)^{s/2}}$

Edit2: A route for proving (2) may be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1073329/proving-int-0-infty-fracxx21e2-pi-x1-dx-1-frac-gamma2/1073360#1073360), differentiating w.r.t to $1/a$ and then use @M.N.C.E's beautiful solution, the integrating back w.r.t to  $1/a$.

Comment: Great! Is there a way to obtain a more general formula, that is with a variable instead of 0?

Comment: After I differentiate the expression under the integral I get something different. How do you get this?

Comment: what exactly is different? it's very straightforward i think

Comment: I've got the following: $$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{1}{4} (\coth (\pi  t)-1) \left(a^2+t^2\right)^{-\frac{s}{2}} \left(2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{a}\right) \cos \left(s \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{a}\right)\right)-\log \left(a^2+t^2\right) \sin \left(s \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{a}\right)\right)\right) \, dt$$ using Mathematica.

Comment: Both forms a actually equivalent. You can show this by using the definition of $\coth$ . furthermore i finally found a nice reference for my calculation with all the details. Only drawback is the fact that it is in german but nevertheless: http://www.mb-schiekel.de/zetafunc.pdf . Have a look at chaper F.3!

Comment: Can the F.3.6 integrals be represented in closed form?

Comment: to be honest, i have the feeling that this is not a case (with the exception of some very specific values). But because i'm not totally sure, i would recommend to ask a new question. I would also be very interested!

Comment: Done: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1287008/can-these-integrals-be-represented-in-closed-form

Comment: Can someone tell me what is the significance of Hermite's formula in the theory of Riemann Zeta function? Can one obtain the functional equation of the Riemann zeta function from the same?